# Memory leak when deploying war file in AWS tomcat

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, memory-leaks, amazon-ec2

I have a small web server running in amazon, and I use amazon default tomcat UI to do the deployment.

However, our server get crushed almost every month, and got the following warning messages:

```
The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):
/mmkms-v1
/mmkms-v1
/mmkms-v1`
```

The way I did deployment is in this UI, click undeploy, and then upload new war file and deploy it again.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pxxwkz1zk6m6mz/Screenshot%202015-07-11%2009.03.40.png?dl=0

Did I do anything wrong, is there a better way to do the deployment?

Comment: this message is normal, when you stop and start tomcat service.

Comment: But my tomcat server stop working every few month, I tried to trouble shoot this issue and think memory leak is the reason.